# How insert full-screen button and bottom bar in interface builder mac os x and bottom bar

Tags: xcode, macos

i can't understand how i can insert the corner top right full screen button in interface builder like this image:

[image]

and then also a bottom bar like this:

[image]

if i create a new application in Xcode the Window is this:

[image]

and there is no corner full screen button and no bottom bar...any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5.2 there is an option in interface builder to set this feature on (just select your window in IB, the option is named "fullscreen" in the window's attributes inspector, and is set to "unsupported" by default, just switch it on "primary window")

For the "bottom bar" ... i think it's just a NSView that is smaller than the NSWindow ^^

Answer (score 1):

You should use Full Screen APIs in your NSApplication.

Go to the below link to learn how to implement this. Also be aware that this option is applicable on Mac OS 10.7.x and Mac OS 10.8.x only. 
[Mac OS X 10.6.x and Xcode compatible with 10.6.x will not support this feature]

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html

Make sure that you have latest version of the OS and Xcode as well.

Answer (score 1):

NSWindow -> size inspector -> content border